# Python - How to implement a zfill on a nested list

Tags: python

I have already posted about this code with a different question and while trying to further develop it, I have stumbled into an error. I want to make my nested list easier to visualize and the problem I bumped into this time is to do with zfill. When trying to change every element in my nested list to a 2 digit number to neaten things up a little, I have made an error. When i run the following code, the numbers are not 2 digits each -

```
import random

def random_2d_array(rows, columns):
    output = []
    iteration = 0
    while iteration != rows:
        i2 = 0
        iteration += 1
        output.append([])
        while i2 != columns:
            i2 += 1
            num = random.randint(1, 10)
            col = output[iteration - 1]
            col.insert(i2 - 1, num)
    for i in output:
        for j in i:
            j = str(j)
            j = j.zfill(2)
    return '\n'.join([str(i) for i in output])

print(random_2d_array(10, 10))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `j` after `j = j.zfill(2)`. You have to set the element in the list to that value:

```
import random

def random_2d_array(rows, columns):
    output = []
    iteration = 0
    while iteration != rows:
        i2 = 0
        iteration += 1
        output.append([])
        while i2 != columns:
            i2 += 1
            num = random.randint(1, 10)
            col = output[iteration - 1]
            col.insert(i2 - 1, num)
    for i in output:
        for j in range(len(i)):
            s = str(i[j])
            i[j] = s.zfill(2)
    return '\n'.join([str(i) for i in output])

print(random_2d_array(10, 10))
```

Result:

```
['01', '03', '08', '03', '06', '03', '06', '10', '10', '08']
['08', '08', '06', '04', '10', '03', '04', '06', '10', '06']
['07', '04', '03', '02', '02', '04', '10', '04', '07', '06']
['05', '10', '10', '04', '09', '09', '03', '10', '09', '09']
['08', '09', '09', '10', '06', '04', '08', '09', '05', '05']
['06', '02', '05', '01', '05', '07', '01', '06', '03', '08']
['06', '06', '04', '09', '06', '01', '02', '10', '08', '01']
['08', '10', '10', '05', '10', '10', '02', '06', '10', '09']
['08', '07', '04', '08', '03', '03', '02', '08', '03', '10']
['10', '07', '02', '07', '05', '05', '10', '04', '06', '08']
```

**Edit**: If you want to remove the quotation marks use

```
return '\n'.join([str(i) for i in output]).replace('\'','')
```

as the last line of your function.

Comment: you can also replace more characters in that line eg `return '\n'.join([str(i) for i in output]).replace('\'','').replace('[','').replace(']','').replace(',','')` that looks even cleaner